# Acessando um ponteiro de ponteiro ( c )

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro

Por que ao descer um nível no ponteiro de ponteiro `** lista` / `* lista` devemos usar os parênteses : `( * lista )`, faço a pergunta pois vi em alguns exemplos pela internet que não utilizavam e também em um livro antigo que peguei pra ler outro dia. Em C++ esse ' modo ' de acesso é utilizado incrementando as posições em determinados casos, certo ?

Comment: Depende do contexto, precisa mostrar exemplos `**lista` e `*(*lista)` são a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve sempre levar em conta o valor da precedência dos operadores, pois eles tem efeito direto sobre o que se deseja obter dos dados que estão sendo manipulados.
Parenteses tem precedência sobre o operador '->', logo ele tem efeito sobre os dados que serão submetidos ao operador seguinte, no caso '->'